# Liferay7 - module (portlet-provider) not refreshing

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

Im working with Liferay 7 and module development.
I created a module of type "portlet-provider" for can change the view of personalBar.
When I deploy it first time, it deploys ok, but after that, new deploys are not refreshing jsp files.
Is important to said that when I deploy the module, via blade or via gradle in Intellij, it deploys ok and also change the OSGI related folder, deleting old version and creating a new one with new jsp ok. 
Even with that in a clear browser (recent removed all cache and temp) does no not refresh the personalBar view, related to new jsp file.

I saw this thread: https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/88515142 , and tested the following.

1) Changed the tomcat timeZone, put the same timezone that I had in my desktop. (GMT-3 ) , it didn't work .

2) The only thing that seems to work is to clear all osgi state content and $liferay_home/work content and restart server as David said in above post.
 But I need a way to can deploy theses modules without having to restart the server

Any help on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you search in the gogo shell for the deployed plugin what are you getting there?

Comment: Using the command "lb" in gogo shell I see this:                          
 507|Active     |    1|dinah-personalbar (1.0.0). Seems its deployed ok

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Comment: @OlafKock , Ok maybe you are right, I will keep in mind for future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About my problem, I had a problem with the priority of the module so the module been deployed were not the same showed in portal.
At the beginning I set the "service.ranking:Integer="+Integer.MAX_VALUE , but I don't know why it was removed and for that the portlet showed was the portal default personal bar.